# Using if with ssl_certificate in nginx for loading SSL certificates

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I have two domains: `foo.com` and `bar.com` which are served by nginx. To avoid duplicating code, I want to put this

```
   [some code]

        if ($host = "foo.com") {
           ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.com/fullchain.pem;
           ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/foo.com/privkey.pem;
        }

        if ($host = "bar.com") {
          ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bar.com/fullchain.pem;
          ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bar.com/privkey.pem;
        }

   [some code there]
```

in my nginx.conf but nginx complains:

```
 * Checking nginx' configuration ...
2023/07/18 20:10:15 [emerg] 2656#2656: "ssl_certificate" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:46
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
2023/07/18 20:10:15 [emerg] 2657#2657: "ssl_certificate" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:46
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It seems like `ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$host/fullchain.pem;            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$host/privkey.pem;` works

Comment: As long as the filename matches the hostname; if you use the same certificate for both domain apex & www subdomain it won't.